# Why is there a difference between my reputations in the menu bar and whats in My Communities list?

Tags: support, reputation

Right now I am confused with the fact that I have 237 points or reputations I am seeing at the top right of the Database Administrators forum, but in YOUR COMMUNITIES list it says 172.

Comment: This was driving me nuts this morning on how I suddenly had more rep without any records of upvotes, etc.  Thanks for asking the question!

Comment: @JohnEisbrener, I can relate, it was driving me nuts as well. I saw on `dba.stackexchange` and `stackoverflow`. It was well received here but on SO, wow they tore me a new one for having banner blindness. I am only human, after hours of looking at code, yeah I guess my eyes go blind to content I was not looking for, I get subjective vision, ha! You are welcome, I am glad it helped.

Comment: imo, there should be some notation of the scoring change in the rep tab linking to the blog post.  They do it with deleted users, so I can't imagine that small UI tweak would have been all that hard, but what do I know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am just guessing but it seems to me this is a caching issue. The [recent move](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) to double the reward for questions means for you that your reputation on this site should increase by 65 points, based on the number of [your questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/113842/daniel?tab=questions) and their current score. That is exactly the difference between the numbers 172 and 237 that you are (were) observing. I suspect the numbers in the Your Community list are fetched from a separate storage that is updated on a schedule, while the actual rep that you can see in the top bar is meant to update immediately. By this point I would expect the numbers to be identical.

Comment: thank you for your civility. I asked the same question on Stack Overflow meta and was downvoted out of existence because of my banner blindness. Yep, that's me, after looking at code for hours, my eyes just blank out I guess. What can I say I am a human being and not a bot.

Comment: @Daniel: It's nice to receive such an appreciation but it's also sad that we are at a point when a perfectly regular (in terms of its tone) answer should even be perceived as particularly civil. The move in question as well as the big ongoing issue that started earlier may have made a lot of people more uptight and jumpy, I guess, but it's still sad.

Comment: oh yes, the move with the recalculation has left some people betrayed, especially on the original SO. I do understand their reasoning as I have always found myself defending SO from certain developers who have said to me that an employer would just see us as having too much time on our hands. It's a sad comment to make, especially when one of these engineers who made it, is self-employed. We are not automatons, we have family and friends, we should have time on our hands and if we are using it for our craft, one would think its a plus for hiring.

Comment: Anyway, this move is seen by many as devaluing SO as being a place that properly captures one skill level based on reputation feedback from our peers. While I am not personally betrayed by it, the decision could give fuel to those who say they were right, it does not measure skill level, its just a bunch of guys with too much time on their hands...super insulting, that comment itself makes me angry.